# How to make skirting boards in Blender geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to add skirting boards to all my walls and I thought geometry nodes would be the fastest way to do it. A flow like:

- `Duplicate Elements` the wall object, so the original wall is untouched
- Add 1.5cm to the x and y dimensions of the duplicate to make the skirting a little wider than the wall
- Set the z dimension of the duplicate to 7cm to make it sit on the floor.

But I don't know how to do steps 2 and 3 at all. I can use transform geometry to scale objects by a percent, but not set absolute values. How to do this please?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach to your problem:

I'm using a separate geometry node to isolate just the bottom edges of the wall. Then, using the curve-to-mesh node, I can use a profile shape to drive the shape of my skirting. I'm using a simple curve object to give it the cornice-bevel look.

You might want to change how the bottom edges are isolated for your setup. In my examle, my walls start at 0 on the z axis, so my compare float node works. If this doesn't work then flush out your question a bit more with pictures of your project etc. so we can best help answer

[image: node setup]

[image: finished result]

my skirting profile object (curve)
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to make another object for the skirting board in my main project. I'd rather just use a 1.5x1.5x7 cm cube that flows along bottom edge, made in the geometry nodes. Is that possible?

Comment: @Richard Yes, you can make a quadrilateral curve primitive in geometry nodes and use that as the profile curve instead. Or you can use a grid mesh primitive, define the size, and then do mesh to curve and use that as your profile curve

Comment: I'm struggling with the selection part - even selecting the whole wall just seems to run three razor blades around the edges. I've added a Blend file in my question trying to implement what you said and would appreciate it if you had any time to look. The object with nodes is walls - _wallSkirting.

Comment: @Richard I believe you need to put your geo nodes modifier last in the stack, after the boolean modifiers. And your geometry nodes object's origin isn't on the ground, thus causing your edge selection to be off. reset transforms and it should work

Comment: Thanks, when I applied location and moved the doorway modifiers up then a skirting appears - but only in the x-axis, not in the y-axis. In the y-axis it's still just a flat wall.